# Show that a functional is differentiable

Tags: derivatives, calculus-of-variations

Show that the following functionals are differentiable in following spaces:

(1): $J\left[y\right] = y(a)\ \ \ in \ \ \ C\left[a,b\right];$

(2): $J\left[y\right] = y(a)\ \ \   in \ \ \ C^{'}\left[a,b\right];$

(3): $J\left[y\right] = \sqrt{1+y^{'2}(a)}\ \ \   in \ \ \ C^{'}\left[a,b\right];$

(4): $J\left[y\right] = \left|y(a)\right|\ \ \   in \ \ \ C\left[a,b\right].$

For (1) and (2) it's clear: $\Delta J=J\left[y+\delta y\right]-J\left[y\right]=\delta y$. It's differentiable, because $\Delta J$ equals to Linear functional of $\delta y$. But, for (3) and (4) it's not very clear. If for (4) I can write: $\Delta J=J\left[y+\delta y\right]-J\left[y\right]=\left|y(a)+\delta y\right|-\left|y(a)\right|$ - here we can see that the first term is a linear functional of $\delta y$ , but second term does not goes to 0, thus it's not differentiable. Book says (3) is differentiable, I have no idea how to show it.